# Matplotlib: How to plot different users on Y-axis and time on X-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Rookie question: How can one go about creating a plot where X-axis is DateTime of a dataset, and Y-axis shows different UserID (or vice versa)?

Datetime is standard `%Y-%m-%d %M:%H:%S` format. UserID is int (e.g., 3441, 3200, 50).

Ideally, the plot shows *range of time* for each user recorded.

So far, this is what I have:

[image]

The main problem is Y-axis is treating the UserIDs like integers... Not sure how to make them look like progress bars and treated like discrete categorical items.

Thanks!

Comment: show your code please

Comment: `enumerate()` the list of the user IDs. Use the new values as Y coordinates. Use the original values as labels.

Comment: that plot was generated with a simple plt.plot(list(map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), data.dates)), list(set(data.ids))

@DYZ I'll try the enumerate method -- thanks!